# Summation of special series

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

Does anybody know how to evaluate  $$\sum_{i=2}^n(i^2)\cdot{i\choose2}$$ How about the general case of $(i^k)*{i\choose2}$? A nice formula would be great!

Comment: Strightforward: $\binom{i}{2}=\frac{i(i-1)}{2}$, and you have to find $\sum i^4$ and $\sum i^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Michael was simply saying that 
$\binom{i}{2}=\frac{i(i-1)}{2}$, and so your sum is just a sum of $i^4$s and $i^3$s, or more generally $i^{k+2}$s and $i^{k+1}$s. So break your sum up into two sums, pull out the constant at the front, and use the general formula for the sum of powers.

The notation is simply LaTeX, which is a common typesetting language in the sciences generally, and very much used on this site.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=2}^n i^k {i\choose2}=\sum_{i=2}^n i^k\cdot\frac{i^2-i}2=\frac12\left(\sum_{i=2}^n i^{k+2}-\sum_{i=2}^n i^{k+1}\right)=\frac12(F_{k+2}(n)-F_{k+1}(n))$$

Where $F_k(n)$ is the $k$-degree [Faulhaber Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula) $\sum_{i=1}^n i^k$